# Sql query with condition If (Update OR Insert)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 cells (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`), I need to update them if they're empty, but not all at the same moment, for example: if empty `A` than update `A` -> set to 10, if `A` is full, than check the `B` cell, if it's empty, put there 10, also this might be assigned to other last two cells `C`,`D`, if 1 cell is updated it's no need to update other 3 cells, if all cells are full than INSERT INTO `table`  (`A`) VALUES(10).

One I did, but it's wrong query, because it's updating all cells:

```
mysql> UPDATE `mytable` SET `A`=10,`B`=10,`C`=10,`D`=10 WHERE `A` IS NULL OR `B` IS NULL OR `C` IS NULL OR `D` IS NULL LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0
```

hope on help.

**updated**
seems it's really a logic trouble in a program, first of all I need to SELECT all cells, this query will be like this:

```
mysql> SELECT `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` FROM `mytable` WHERE `A` IS NULL OR `B` IS NULL OR `C` IS NULL OR `D` IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

And after that do the next step.

Comment: Do u wanna update or insert the same table? are there are 2 tables u r refering table, mytable?

Comment: if insert n update are on same table, then insert on duplicate alone will work

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure seems particularly strange: perhaps an alternative structure would achieve your desired outcome in a better way?  However, without further information about the problem you're trying to model, you can perform the updates you mention with the following:

```sql
LOCK TABLES mytable WRITE;

INSERT INTO `table` (A) SELECT 10 FROM mytable WHERE
  A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL AND D IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE mytable SET
  D = IF(A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL AND D IS NULL, 10, D),
  C = IF(A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NULL, 10, C),
  B = IF(A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NULL, 10, B),
  A = IF(A IS NULL, 10, A);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO <table> 
 VALUES (1, 2, 3 ,4) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4
```

But I think this will not serve your purpose. You will need to write a logic in PHP or your server side language only.